# Store URLSessionDownloadTask in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsessiontask

I want to save `URLSessionDownloadTask` in core data when app is gone in closed state or my download state is changed e.g from waiting state to downloading state or to completed state.

All other attributes of my custom class are stored perfectly but app crashes when it stores download task.

reason to crash is

> [__NSCFLocalDownloadTask encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff189f181c0
>   -[NSKeyedArchiver dealloc]: warning: NSKeyedArchiver deallocated without having had -finishEncoding called on it.
>    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFLocalDownloadTask encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff189f181c0'

this is my class

```
class VideoDownloadModel : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var videoID : NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var vid : Video?
    @NSManaged var downloadTask : URLSessionDownloadTask?
    @NSManaged var downloadStatus : String?
}
```

storing it like this

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: (COREDATA_ENTITY_Description?.name)!)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "videoID == %@", videoModel.videoID!)

        do {
            let result = try COREDATA_CONTEXT.fetch(request)
            print(result)
            var vidArr = result as! [VideoDownloadModel]

            if vidArr.count != 0 {
                vidArr[0] = videoModel

                COREDATA_MANAGER.saveContext()
            }

        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
        }
```

when `URLSessionDownlaodTask` is `nil` it works fine but when any download is started it crashes on saving.

scenerio :

- I initialized my custom class object with all attributes but set task to nil.
- I store that object in core data it saved perfectly.
- I initialize the task of that object the download work perfectly.
- Then i update the object in core data while updating the app got crash because URLSssionTask is not inheriting from NSCoding. so it don't have encoding and decoding methods.

I want some solution to solve this issue

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show _how_ you do it (code).

Comment: i have added it in my post please review it.

Comment: I strongly doubt that you get the task resumed after fetching it from Core Data.

Comment: Vadian no task is not resumed.

let me share 1 complete scenerio :

1- I initialized my custom class object with all attributes but set task to nil.
2- I store that object in core data it saved perfectly.
3- I initialize the task of that object the download work perfectly.
4- Then i update the object in core data while updating the app got crash because URLSssionTask is not inheriting from NSCoding.
so it don't have encoding and decoding methods.

Now i want some solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save the `URLSessionDownloadTask` in Core Data because-- as you mentioned-- it doesn't conform to `NSCoding`. In many cases the answer would be to write your own code to convert to/from `Data` but that doesn't work in this case. A `URLSessionDownloadTask` can only be created by a `URLSession`, so you can't serialize and deserialize the task object.

That doesn't really matter though because saving and restoring them doesn't make sense. A `URLSessionDownloadTask` represents something that is in progress while the app is running. If your app is closed, that activity ends. Restoring a `URLSessionDownloadTask` after the app closes and relaunches doesn't make sense because there's no activity for it to represent. Basically, even if you could store the task object and restore it, it would be useless after restoring. There's no reason to bother.

If your interest is that you want to resume incomplete downloads, you'll have to start over from the beginning. Create your `URLSession` and then use it to create a new `URLSessionDownloadTask`. If your interest is in getting information about a background download, you can use the session object with `getTasksWithCompletionHandler(_:)` to find out whether they completed.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but can u please guide me how youtube resume download after app is relaunches after quite?

Answer (score 0):

Saving `URLSessionDownloadTask` doesn't make sense. You would actually want to save the data obtained from `downloadTask.cancel(byProducingResumeData: )` while pausing.

Once you need to resume the download create a new downloadtask with the saved data by using `downloadTaskWithResumeData(:)` and resume.

**When app is terminated - dosen't include the case when the app is forcefully terminated by the user.**

The apple documentation on URLSession clearly explains what to do when app is terminated.
From the docs - *In both iOS and OS X, when the user relaunches your app, your app should immediately create background configuration objects with the same identifiers as any sessions that had outstanding tasks when your app was last running, then create a session for each of those configuration objects. These new sessions are similarly automatically reassociated with ongoing background activity.*

**When user forcefully terminate the app**

In this case, URLSession delegate `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` will be fired, in which the `userInfo` dict in `error` object will have the resume data corresponding to the key `NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData`, which could be used to resume the task using `downloadTask.cancel(byProducingResumeData: )`. Also please note that you will have to typecast `error` to `NSError` to retrieve the `userInfo` dict.

It would be good to read through the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1) before using `NSURLSession`

Comment: yes you are right, but how to handle the case when downloadTask.cancel(byProducingResumeData: ) can not be done. e.g when user forcefully exit the application?

Comment: Sorry for being late here. I have updated the answer. See if that helps (in case you have not already found out the solution :D)